# How do I view emoji in Google Chrome in Lion?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, emoji

This question is an extension of [Daniel L.'s question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41228/why-do-emoji-like-appear-when-i-use-safari-but-not-chrome) and [my own question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40479/how-do-i-view-emoji-in-google-chrome-on-os-x-prior-to-10-7). I upgraded to Lion after asking my question. I'd like to be able to view emoji in Chrome when using Lion. 
So stuff like this:    I'd like to be able to see in Chrome. How do I do this? If possible, I'd like to use the system font that's already included on OS X Lion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it should actually work, which is an advantage.

Create a service in Automator. The service takes **no input**.

Two actions.

### First action:

**Run AppleScript**
Here's the script:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
    tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Google Chrome" to set myvar to value of text field 1 of tool bar 1 of window 1
    if myvar contains "://" then
        -- do nothing
    else
        set myvar to "http://" & myvar
    end if
    return myvar

end run
```

### Second action:

**Website Popup**

Assign it a keystroke and you're good to go.

[image]